# Batman: Arkham Knight Skins Pack

Tags: ps4, batman-arkham-knight

I finish the whole game and now I realized that the pack says "installing" when I downloaded and is stuck there. Any ideas? how do I install properly the pack? I re-downloaded and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a semi-common problem with different DLC and games for the PS4.

Sony has included an option in the PS4 OS that let's you '[restore your licenses](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/license.html)' which basically deletes the local licenses information and downloads it from the PSN servers:

Comment: This is useful, thanks. But sadly, does not fix my problem. :(